# Mapping a different factor to the legend labels in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to give additional information in my legend. I want to give each graph a unique color using an ID. But my legend labels I want to contain information from a factor that can be equal for different IDs but is always constant for one ID.
Example:

```
mydata <- data.frame(x=rep(1:10,5),
y=rep((1:10),5)*sort(rep((10:14)/10,10)),
ID=sort(rep(1:5,10)),
info1=sort(rep(c("A","B","C","D","C"),10)),
info2=sort(rep(c("GG","HH","HH","GG","II"),10)))

ggplot(mydata,aes(x=x,y=y,color=as.factor(ID)))+geom_line()
```

This gives me the plot as it should be plus a legend showing the IDs.

[image]

Now my question ist how to replace the IDs by the factors in info1 while keeping distinct colors for each graph. And even better would be to include information from info1 and info2 in one legend...

I know how to use an additional invisibe plot to get additional legends, but this is not quite what I want:

```
ggplot(mydata,aes(x=x,y=y,color=as.factor(ID)))+geom_line() +
geom_point(aes(shape=NA,size=info1,fill=info2)) + guides(color=FALSE)
```

[image]

Instead, I would like the legend like in the first picture, but the information (label) from the second picture. Of course, taking the information from the data.frame only, not giving it explicitly.

Thank you for suggestions

Comment: So you have 5 colors but 7 items in your legend that are showing size, how are you trying to pair these together?

Comment: Nathan, when you look at how the data frame (mydata) ist constructed, you'll notice that I have only 5 "items" with different sets of factors (ID, info1, info2) describing them. ID is unique, info1 has 4 levels and info2 has 3 levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would gluing `ID`, `info1`, and `info2` together and using that as the ID work?

```
mydata$ID2 = paste(mydata$ID,paste(mydata$info1),paste(mydata$info2), sep='-')

ggplot(mydata,aes(x=x,y=y,color=as.factor(ID2)))+geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I would call it an acceptable workaround, thank you Gene.

It seems there is no pure ggplot way to do this. Where actually this is a very common task, putting some metadata on experimental results...

Comment: @lambu0815, if this works, would you mark it as the answer? Thanks :)

Comment: Gene, I'd like to keep it open for another day or two.

Comment: Ok, there is, of course, a drawback to this solution - I'll have to include the unique ID, otherwise 3&4 would fall together as the two factors of metadata both are the same. But they are still independent experiments...

Comment: @lambu0815, I am not sure I follow. If one were to remove the ID field, the two would be indistinguishable on the graph which, I presume, would confuse the graph interpreter.

Comment: Well, maybe you're right. Anyway your idea works and helped me go on. Thank you.